# Wrong address is returned when signing with Safe wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

I am trying to integrate safe wagmi connecter into our app. https://wagmi.sh/react/api/connectors/safe
The problem is that after connecting the wallet, we require the sign a message to prove their identity.
And when I try to verify the message by using ethers.verifyMessage(message, signature)
It's returning a wrong address. Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: What do you mean by "a wrong address"? Have you tried using [`useSignMessage`](https://wagmi.sh/react/api/hooks/useSignMessage) from Wagmi instead of ethers.js? If you could also provide a code snippet pointing to where the error occurs, it would help us help you solve this issue. Thank you!